CDD on the surface of a slab and in other types of (finite) systems
What would be the appropriate method of calculating the difference in charges for this type of system?
For composite systems it is usually something like:
$$ \Delta\rho = \rho_{system}-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\rho_{i},$$
where N is the total number of subsystems. So here it would be something like:
$$ \Delta\rho = \rho_{bulk}-\rho_{slab}\; \text{?}$$
And for example for a finite nanowire, does the same apply (at the ends of the wire)?
